# Sorting Array of CLLocationDegrees Objects

Tags: ios, swift, cllocationcoordinate2d

I'm trying to sort 2 arrays of CLLocationDegrees Objects such that I can determine a minimum and maximum latitude and longitude to centre a map with Swift.

```
var latitudes = [CLLocationDegrees]()
var longditudes = [CLLocationDegrees]()

self.latitudes.append(mylocation.coordinate.latitude)
self.longditudes.append(mylocation.coordinate.longitude)

latitudes = latitudes.sort({ $0 < $1 })
longditudes = longditudes.sort({ $0 < $1 })
```

When I go to sort the arrays I get the error: "() is not convertible to type [(CLLocationDegrees)]"

I'm not sure that I understand this, CLLocationDegree objects are stored as Double values, why can I not sort them in this manner?

Comment: Are self.latitudes and var latitudes supposed to be the same variable? Same with self.longditudes and longditudes? Because right now, you're sorting an empty array...

Comment: Yes they are, however the arrays are declared globally and appended to within a separate function so I referenced them with 'self.'

Comment: My point is that you never put anything into the `latitudes` and `longditudes` arrays you're trying to sort... only into `self.latitudes` and `self.longditudes`. You're sorting empty arrays.

Comment: @LyndseyScott That's not the issue, `sort` on an empty array just leaves the array unchanged. And you can see from the OP's code that he's adding numbers to his array.

Comment: @Abizern Yes, that's not the thing causing the error, but the arrays he's sorting are 100% empty. He's NOT adding numbers to the same arrays that he's sorting.

Comment: That's true, although it's likely that the OP is not showing all of his code; if this is within a class or struct, then this legal code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put this into a playground to see two ways of doing what you are trying to do

```
import UIKit
import CoreLocation

var latitudes : [CLLocationDegrees] = []
var longditudes :[CLLocationDegrees] = []

latitudes.append(100.0) // Just using a Double as an example
longditudes.append(120.0)

latitudes.sort() {
    $0 < $1
}

longditudes.sort({ $0 < $1 })
```

`sort` performs the sort in place so you can't assign it to itself.

Comment: Thanks for bringing that up, that seems to have fixed it!

Answer (score 2):

Just try to read what compiler says. "`()` is not convertible to the type `[(CLLocationDegrees)]`. The `()` means `Void`. Thats right. `Void` is just typealiased empty tuple which is `()`. So the compiler says you are assigning `Void` to `CLLocationDegrees` array. That means `latitudes.sort({ $0 < $1 })` returns `Void`.

From here you can continue to read @Abizern's answer.